# Set Kendo UI Window values globally

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-window

I'm working with a lot of Kendo UI windows. Is there some way to specify default values somehow globally? Or maybe a more realistic version, can I create some parent with predefined values and then just overwrite the values I need to change?

For example, I want the same error behavior and a modal parameter for all of the windows, so I would like to do something like:

```
$("#parentWindow").kendoWindow({
     modal: true,
     error: function () {
          this.close();
          new Notification().error();
     }
});
```

And then use the parent window as a base for new windows:

```
$("#newWindow").kendoWindow({
     title: "This window should have the options (modal and error) of the parentWindow",     
}).??getTheRestOfTheValuesFromParent()??;
```

Or rewrite some parameter:

```
$("#newWindow2").kendoWindow({
     modal: false,
     title: "A window with overwritten modal parameter",     
}).??getTheRestOfTheValuesFromParent()??;
```

Is it somehow possible to achieve this, is there any possibility of something like C# inheritance?
Maybe it's a stupid question, but I'm not so familiar with JS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I highly encourage you to create your own *wrapper* code over all - or at least those more complex - kendo widgets. My team has been doing it for years in a project we use kendo for everything and we are having very positivelly results. The main purpose is what you need: a global behaviour. If after thousand windows coded over your project, you need to change them all, just change the wrapper. It's just a simple jQuery function:

```
$.fn.MyWindow = function(options) {
    var $target = $(this);
    var widget = {
        _defaultOptions: {
            actions: ["Minimize", "Maximize", "Close"],
            visible: false,
            width: 400,
            height: 400,
            modal: true
        },
        _options: options || {},
        _target: $target,
        _widget: null,

        _init: function() {
            this._manageOptions();
            this._createWidget();

            return this;
        },

        _manageOptions: function() {
            // Here you can perform some validations like displaying an error when a parameter is missing or whatever
            this._options = $.extend(this._options, this._defaultOptions);
        },

        _createWidget: function() {
            this._widget = this._target.kendoWindow(this._options).data("kendoWindow");

            // Create here some behaviours that the widget doesn't haves, like closing the window when user click the black overlay
            if (this._options.closeOnOverlayClick) {
                $('body').off('click', '.k-overlay').on('click', '.k-overlay', function() {
                    this._widget.close();
                }.bind(this));
            }
        },

        Show: function(center) {
            if (center) {
                this._widget.center();
            }

            this._widget.open();
        }
    };

    return widget._init();
};

var wnd = $("#wnd").MyWindow({
    title: "My first window",
    closeOnOverlayClick: true // Your own parameter
});

// Now you work with your own functions:
wnd.Show(true);
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EqoqU).

There are so many customizations, like your own events - some of those kendo's widgets doesn't haves - etc..

Comment: Thank you, it looks very useful

Answer (score 3):

I will just add that there is an article([here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/create-custom-kendo-widget)) about creating custom Kendo widgets where you can find more information about the specifics of different scenarios that may be implemented.

Comment: I knew that there was something official to wrap a widget, but I could not remember where to find it. Nice article.

Comment: Definitely useful, thank you very much, but as there's a specific code, I'd rather accept the first answer.

Answer (score 3):

Ι had a case like yours with kendo windows, kendo grids and kendo dropdownlists. For that I created HtmlHelpers for all my elements and called them when I needed to. Since you are using kendo asp.net-mvc I would recommend to look at this way.

```
    public static WindowBuilder GlobalKendoWindow(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        return helper.Kendo().Window()
            .Draggable()
            .Animation(true)
            .Visible(false)
            .AutoFocus(true)
            .Modal(true)
            .Scrollable(true)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "atn-modal-container" })
            .Actions(actions => actions.Minimize().Close())
            .Deferred();
    }
```

and render it in my Html like this

```
@(Html.GlobalKendoWindow()
    .Name("addCandidateDialog")
    .Title(Html.GetResource(cps, "AddCandidateDialogTitle"))
    .LoadContentFrom("AddCandidate", "Candidate")
    .Events(events => events.Open("athena.addCandidacy.onAddCandidateOpen").Close("athena.addCandidacy.onAddCandidateClose"))
)
```

Comment: Looks good, but we're preferring JS syntax right now, as we need some behavior which is difficult (or maybe not possible) to set in this Kendo MVC version. Thanks for the suggestion, hopefully, I use it one day.